# How exactly does "Gesture Border" work?

Tags: python

I started to mess around with the key configurations in Blender 2.8 to make it feel like Maya LT.

And there I see Gesture Border under Border Select. It seems to affect how Border Select works. I tried to find its definition on Blender Python API Reference, but, I found... nothing.

Anyway, I still haven't figured out how to make Selection in Blender feel like Maya. Please tell me if you ever encountered this too and what did you do. Thanks!

EDIT 1 (2018/6/1 10:20 SMT+8):
I didn't notice it before I ask this question but actually, Gesture Border input settings can also be found in previous versions. Maybe it's irrelevant to version, though I'm not entirely sure.

At this moment I think I should remove "in Blender 2.8" from the title, but I decided to keep it for clarification since there's a comment telling why this question was downvoted.

I still want to know how Gesture Border works though. But I won't talk about experimental versions anymore.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about unfinished experimental development software

Comment: I've also wondered about Gesture Border and can't find any documentation on it. I'd like to know how it works, too. Since Gesture Border has been implemented for quite a while and is not 2.8 specific I don't think the question should be closed.